# How to Set a specific Image to a specific array position?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a `UICollectionView` for Horizontal scrolling having six images in the `array`. What I want is when an item at index path x(1) is clicked an array with images to be set on remaining items(0,2,3,4,5)  except position 1. Can we set a specific image at a specific position of an array if yes then how?

In the case of `Android`, it is like

```
if (selectedPosition < 0) {
  viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(coloredSmiley[position]);
} else {
  viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(selectedPosition == position ? coloredSmiley[position] : greySmiley[position]);
}


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var selectedImageButton = -1
    var imagearray = ["AngrysmIcon1", "UpsetsmIcon2", "ConfusedsmIcon3", "MehsmIcon4", "CurioussmIcon5" , "HappysmIcon6"]
    var bwimagearray = ["AngrysmIcon1Inactive", "UpsetsmIcon2Inactive", "ConfusedsmIcon3Inactive", "MehsmIcon4Inactive", "CurioussmIcon5Inactive", "HappysmIcon6Inactive"]

    var positiontag = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return self.positiontag.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UIcollectionViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.imagev.image = UIImage(named: imagearray[indexPath.row])
            return cell

    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            return 1
    }

    internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)   {

        selectedImageButton = indexPath.row

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! UIcollectionViewCellCollectionViewCell
        if selectedImageButton < 0 {

            //cell.imagev.image = bwimagearray[indexPath.row]

        } else {
            cell.imagev.image = UIImage(named: imagearray[indexPath.row])

        } 
    }
}
```

Where `selectedposition` is global with value -1

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can use `UICollectionViewDelegate` method `didSelectItemAt` and can fetch the _index position_ of the _item_ that was clicked which corresponds to the image inside array

Comment: It's pretty hard to read the code inside the comment, Please **format** the code and _add it inside the question_ as well .

Comment: yes I am using it Thanks

Comment: @MayankWadhwa So , you just want to fetch the image that was clicked right?

Comment: Shubham Bakshi thanks for replying : the question is I want that when image at index path 1 is clicked the images at remaining positions which is 0,2,3,4,5 should have different images set on them also image at position 1 should have a unique image

Comment: Aren't the images in all the `collectionViewCells` already unique according to the `imagearray`? Kindly clarify your problem statement.

Comment: i have 6 black images and 6 white images. default white images are set on imageview on clicking any one the clicked one remains white but others become black and if one of the black images is clicked the one which is clicked turns white and the remaining go black

Comment: @MayankWadhwa Do you want to set image from `imagearray` for selected item and images from `bwimagearray` for rest of the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **Android** snippet, i believe you need to change `cellForRowAt` as below,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UIcollectionViewCellCollectionViewCell
      let imageName: String
      if selectedImageButton < 0 {
          imageName = imagearray[indexPath.row]
      } else {
          imageName = selectedImageButton == indexPath.row ? imagearray[indexPath.row] : bwimagearray[indexPath.row]
      }
      cell.imagev.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
      return cell

}
```

And then set the `selectedImageButton` in `didSelectItemAt` and reload the `collectionView`,

```
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)   {
        selectedImageButton = indexPath.row
        collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**Note:** `ReloadData` may not be recommended and you should look for some more reactive way to notify the cells to update image.

Comment: Thank you Kamran You are my saviour for the day Awesome Answer

Comment: I have marked it, bro. Can you please tell the significance of   every varaiable in the below line          imageName = selectedImageButton == indexPath.row ? imagearray[indexPath.row] : bwimagearray[indexPath.row]

Comment: @MayankWadhwa You marked the wrong answer. This is a single line `if-condition`where it checks if `selectedImageButton` is equal to cell's row then take the image from the `imagearray` else take the imageName from the `bwimagearray`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and apologies for wrongly marking the answer now i have marked your answer please check

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `cellForItemAt`

```
if cell.isSelected {
    cell.imagev.image = UIImage(named: imagearray[indexPath.row])
} else {
    cell.imagev.image = UIImage(named: bwimagearray[indexPath.row])
}
```

and following to `didSelectItemAt`

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

But would recommend to move the logic that set all this to cell something like below mentioned

```
class UIcollectionViewCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        get {
            return super.isSelected
        }
        set {
            super.isSelected = newValue
            updateImage()
        }
    }

    private func updateImage() {
        if isSelected {
            imagev.image = UIImage(named: imagearray[indexPath.row])
        } else {
            imagev.image = UIImage(named: bwimagearray[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `UIcollectionViewCellCollectionViewCell`, there is no `imagearray` or `bwimagearray` so this will not compile.

Comment: @Kamran this need to be moved there,  The code mentioned above gives an idea, it's not the complete solutions.